# Power Bi web.contents Variables

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Please excuse my lack of knowledge in explaining my problem as i have only just started learning Power Bi.

I am attempting to return data by using a dynamic variable within my source url.

Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.****.com/jobs/**{ID}**/invoices", [Headers=[Authorization="Bearer "&GetToken()]]))

I have successfully returned the data i needed from multiple queries [Blank Query 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9JUs.png) [Query Names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeyDu.png)

However, i am trying to run a final query in which a job ID needs to be specified.

Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.****.com/jobs/**{ID}**/invoices", [Headers=[Authorization="Bearer "&GetToken()]]))

With the bold item being the variable.

I have successfully returned values by hard coding the variable (seen below).
[Hard coded variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmUnP.png)

However, i would like to make dynamic in that it will return the values for all the Job ID's witin the "jobs" table.

[Job Id's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5oYc.png)

I don't know if what im asking is possible, or if my explanation is good enough, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [custom function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/custom-function).

1. Make a function out of your above query by adding `(ID) =>` in the first line and separating "ID" in your URL string.

```
(ID) =>
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.****.com/jobs/{" & ID & "}/invoices", [Headers=[Authorization="Bearer "&GetToken()]]))
in
    Source
```

Of cause you can add all your other transformation steps too.

2. Now take your JobIDs table and add a column by invoking a custom function, select the above function and take the ID parameter from your ID column.
3. For every row you'll get a separate table and all that's left is simply expanding these tables into your query.

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Peter, 

Thank you for your help!

It was a bit tricky but it solved my problem!