# Power Query - Populate column through REST API

Tags: rest, powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a list of IDs in Power Query and would like to call and API to return some information about each. As there is no direct API that allows me to pull the information for my entire list, I have to call the API for each row in my table.

The API requires a dynamic access token, which I already have a function that takes care of (GetToken()).

I have followed this [guide](http://blog.matticus.net/2018/07/powerbi-calling-rest-api-for-each-row.html). The guide adds a custom column for which I have written the following code:

```
Json.Document(
Web.Contents(
    Text.Combine({"https://urlthatholdstheinfo.com/", [id]}), [Headers=[Authorization="Bearer "& GetToken()]]))
```

When I close the editor, I get this classic error:

### "Expression.Error: The 'Authorization' header is only supported when connecting anonymously. These headers can be used with all authentication types: Accept, Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Cache-Control, Content-Type, If-Modified-Since, Prefer, Range, Referer

I have previously mitigated this in the Data Source Settings by setting the Permission to "Anonymous". However, I can not find this query in those settings, so I don't know where to change this.

I have unsuccessfully been looking for a way to parse a parameter to Web.Content, that tells the query to do this with Anonymous settings, but it does not seem to exist.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74652314/power-bi-web-contents-variables) variation as well, but I get the same error

Any thoughts on what I can do?

**UPDATE:**

The answer for this post works, with a small addition. After implementing the answer, the error still occurred. It was resolved by creating a blank query with a fixed id number instead of parsing the column as an argument to the function. This allowed me to go to "Data source settings" and change the permission for the query to Anonymous, which also fixed the problem for the function and the custom column.

```
let
Source = 
Json.Document(
    Web.Contents(
            "https://https://urlthatholdstheinfo.com/id", 
                [Headers=[Authorization="Bearer "& GetToken()]])),
in
   Source
```

Also, be sure to not have the curly brackets that are in the original code of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of IDs you can make a custom function that uses appropriate constructors for `RelativePath` like David suggests. Here is a function you can paste into a blank query, which you can specify using `Invoke Custom Function` on your list of IDs:

```
let
    Source = (ID as text) =>
    Json.Document(
        Web.Contents(
            "https://urlthatholdstheinfo.com/",
            [
                Headers=[Authorization="Bearer "& GetToken()] ,
                RelativePath=ID
            ]
        ]
        )
    )
in 
    Source
```

Make sure your ID column is in `text` format - or change the custom function above to:

```
let
    Source = (ID as number) =>
    Json.Document(
        Web.Contents(
            "https://urlthatholdstheinfo.com/",
            [
                Headers=[Authorization="Bearer "& GetToken()] ,
                RelativePath=Text.From(ID)
            ]
        ]
        )
    )
in 
    Source
```

Comment: I use your exact code, but gets:
An error occurred in the ‘GetStatus2’ query. Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type List to type Text.
Details:
    Value=[List]
    Type=[Type]

Comment: You need to expand your list first, so that you have a column with one ID per row. The function does not expand lists.

Comment: Do I do that in the function or in my table that invokes the function?

Comment: In your table that invokes the function. When you invoke the function, you specify both the function and which column that contains the row-by-row ID parameter to pass to the function - the latter is the result of this expanded list.

Comment: I'm a bit of a rookie in this, so I'm not sure how to do this. I thought it would be most appropriate to make this it's own question. I'm pretty sure your answer has helped and will mark it as an answer when I'm sure, thanks :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75444958/power-query-m-expression-error-list-to-text

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure this problem arises because of the way you're constructing your URL using Text.Combine. Can you rewrite your query to use the RelativePath header
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/web-contents

Comment: I think this is in the right direction. Now i get:

An error occurred in the ‘’ query. Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type List to type Text.
Details:
    Value=[List]
    Type=[Type]

Comment: Post your updated query and ideally some sample data being fed into the URL.

Comment: I think this exact problem "Expression.Error: The 'Authorization' header is only supported when connecting anonymously" has now been solved hasn't it? Your new problem is something different.

Comment: Yea i Think you are right. I have moved my new problem to a new post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75444958/power-query-m-expression-error-list-to-text

I will just double check that it works and mark the answer.